# It would be nice to search only my answers

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, answers, search

Every once in a while when a very similar question is asked, I'll want to post a reference to an answer I gave for another question to help provide some more ideas to the asker.

The problem is that dealing with the "your answers" list is not easy.  If you click an answer on any page but the first, and it turns out it wasn't the one you were looking for, and then you go back, of course you're back to the first page of your answers.

I would love to have a filter box or a search box to simply narrow down the list of questions that I've answered to assist me in finding the right one.

Comment: Open link in a tab?  But I would like to see a feture like "Refrance another Post", which would open up a search/list of posts.

Answer (score 9):

You can do this using the `is:answer` and `user:me` filters on the site search. Simply tack these on to any search, and it will filter it, showing just your answers.

As an example, if you wanted to find all of your answers for the [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) tag, you would search

> [c#] is:answer user:me

Note: "me" here is a shortcut that will plug your user ID into the search. You can filter a search by user ID for any user (or yourself!) by replacing "me" with the user ID.

Answer (score 4):

You can search the titles of questions you answered:

https://stackoverflow.com/api/useranswers.html?page=1&pagesize=10000&userId=54680&sort=Recent

You could search this by installing (and editing a bit) my [favorites-search greasemonkey script](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3739/greasemonkey-searchable-favorites-list-on-every-page), and change the datasource from **userfavorites** to **useranswers**.

#### Update:

I just re-examined the script, and the *useranswers* page, and it looks like you'll have to edit the

```
$("h3 a", data)
```

selector to match

```
$("div div a")
```

instead.

Comment: It would still be nice to have a friendly UI for it.  A lot of scrolling through my old answers is "visual memory", looking for answered vs. unanswered and # of votes in the little box.

Comment: My script is find-as-you-type. Pretty friendly. Just case-sensitive, unfortunately.

Comment: It'd be really nice to be able to get the text of your questions and answers in one page